# Important phrases in emails

Tags: english-to-german, phrase

Do you know or do you have a source of German important phrases that can be used in emails?

For example, I am using some phrases like

- If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to contact me.
- kindly find attached
- I hope everything going well by you

etc.

I want in general to learn these phrases in German. I don't like to translate it, I prefer if someone has experience about such phrases teach me so that I can write it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a website where German phrases in e-mails are translated into English.

This site is made for German native speakers who want to write correct English letters, therefore the descriptions are in German. But I think you will find what you want:

**business e-mails:**
[bab.la Phrasen: Geschäftskorrespondenz | Brief (Deutsch-Englisch)](http://de.bab.la/phrasen/geschaeftlich/email/deutsch-englisch/)

**private e-mails:**
[bab.la Phrasen: Persönliche Korrespondenz | E-Mail (Deutsch-Englisch)](http://de.bab.la/phrasen/persoenlich/email/deutsch-englisch/)